# How to tell which (sequential or parallel) version of Intel MKL is linked?

Tags: blas, intel-mkl

Recently I am using Umfpack with Intel MKL BLAS. To link the library to a program one has to link mkl_rt.lib / mkl_rt.so. However there is no word which version: sequential or parallel of library is linked.

Anyone could help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the precise link command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that MKL has the threaded parallel and serial functions in one unified library. You can try setting OMP_NUM_THREADS or MKL_NUM_THREADS to a range of values and see how the performance varies. Setting either to 1 will give you the serial behavior.

Comment: I should add, that you probably have to pick ONE of these to set to 1 and leave the other unset. IF MKL_NUM_THREADS=m and OMP_NUM_THREADS=n, I don't know which you get. Read the manual to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

There is some good information here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-calling-intel-mkl-functions-from-multi-threaded-applications

- set MKL_NUM_THREADS=n
- call mkl_set_num_threads(n)

Answer (score 1):

Use the MKL link line advisor to determine what library that corresponds to.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor

If you choose "Single Dynamic Library", it uses "mkl_rt.lib" and it looks like threading is active.

Answer (score 0):

The results of these two versions should be the same. It's up to you to decide whether you want to utilize multiple cores or not.

Comment: My question is: If there's only one lib file for linking, how do I know if my program uses parallel or sequential functions? Or: how can I use parallel or sequential when I need one.